# specifing table data width

Tags: php, html, css

this code does not recognize the td witdh values I have put, but I can't differenciate between table and cell width/height in the style tag (hence table height being only 25px) which means I know I have done something wrong but cant seem to fix it, any advice would be much appreciated, Thanks

```
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
table, td; 
table
{
width:800px;height:25px;
}
table
{
position: absolute; right: 100px; top: 80px;
}
table
{
 border-collapse:collapse; 
}
td
{
border-spacing:0px;
}

td
{
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-bottom-width:1px;
border-color:black;
}
td
{
background-color:grey;
color:red;
}
td
{
text-align:center;
}

</style>
</head>";

while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
echo"
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td width='20'></td>
<td width='400'>First Name:</td>
<td width='340'>{$info['firstname']}</td>
<td width='40'><a href='changefirstname.php'>edit</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='20'><td>Last Name:</td>
<td>{$info['lastname']}</td>
<td><a href='changelastname.php'>edit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='20'></td>
<td>email:</td>
<td>{$info['email']}</td>
<td><a href='changeemail.php'>edit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='20><td>password:</td>
<td>********</td>
<td><a href='changepassword.php'>edit</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>";
```

Comment: why do you have repeated selectors for table and td? You can specify once and put all the styles inside

Comment: this is to make it visually easier for someone to spot an error, the actual code i'm using is not like this

Comment: that is misleading. You should be posting the actual code or something very close. That's how we can know what you are doing right or wrong

Comment: you should make your question very clear, that what the error is and what problems you are facing..

Answer (score 2):

You missed quote in the line near width='20:

```
<td width='20><td>password:</td>
```

make it

```
<td width='20'><td>password:</td>
```

It may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try to put the CSS style in the other file.

and your code

Usually i do this for my php code

```
 <table>
<?php
   $no=1;
   while ($data = mysql_fetch_array)
   {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>".$data[your_table_column]."</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
   }  
   $no++;

 ?>
 </table>
```

I think the problem is just inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

Your style should all be in one selector for each element like this

```
table
{

    width:800px;height:25px;
    position: absolute; right: 100px; top: 80px;

    border-collapse:collapse; 

}

td
{

    border-spacing:0px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-color:black;
    background-color:grey;
    color:red;
    text-align:center;

}

td.col1 {width:20px}
td.col2 {width:400px}
td.col3 {width:340px}
td.col4 {width:40px}
```

in your html code, add the classes

```
<td class='col1'></td>
<td class='col2'>First Name:</td>
<td class='col3'>{$info['firstname']}</td>
<td class='col4'><a href='' /></td>
```

And also, the height of your table is 25px

Comment: thats much better thanks, do you know how I can edit the code to specify the width of each cell?

Comment: forget what I just wrote, I am such a fool. the script is fine but because the text was aligned centrally and I thought it was aligned left it made it look like the cells were a diffrent size to what they were. But thanks a lot for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should remove this line `table, td;` it is useless.

Then, you should combine your styling like this :

```
table {
     /* Table */
}

tr {
     /* Row */
}

td {
     /* Cell */
}
```

For your main problem, you either need to :

Apply classes to your `td`s with fixed width

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="first">First</td>
        <td class="second">Second</td>
        <td class="third">Third</td>
        <td class="fourth">Fourth</td>
    </tr>
</table>

.first { width: 20px; }
.second { width: 400px; }
.third { width: 340px; }
.fourth { width: 40px; }
```

Don't use classes but CSS selectors

```
td:nth-child(1) { width: 20px; }
td:nth-child(2) { width: 400px; }
td:nth-child(3) { width: 340px; }
td:nth-child(4) { width: 40px; }
```

In any case, you don't need your `width='...'` in the HTML markup.

Here is a simplified example : http://jsfiddle.net/morgi/csqAb/1/